# AttributeError: ,_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python

This code works perfectly fine outside of Blender, but the `next()` function does not appear to exist in Blender..

```
while line:
    if(line == "POSITION:\n"):
        POS1 = '[' + file.next().replace(' ',', ').replace('\n','') + ']'
        POS2 = '[' + file.next().replace(' ',', ').replace('\n','') + ']'
        POS3 = '[' + file.next().replace(' ',', ').replace('\n','') + ']'
        POS4 = '[' + file.next().replace(' ',', ').replace('\n','') + ']'

    try:
        line = file.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
file.close()
return
```

(Not all of my code, just the part that reads my file)

Comment: Please post a sample script which shows the error and can run on its own, this seems like it may be more of a bug report too.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.6x comes with its own Python in Version 3.3.x, and in Py3k it's `__next__()`.

You can do simpler, however:

```
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this:

:

```
with open("updated_test.csv",'w') as f1:
with open("Review.csv",'r+') as f:
    f.next()
    for line in f:
        f1.write(line)
```